# Riverpod won't refresh when state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

SOLUTION

This worked for some reason

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final tabProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TabEncap, int>((ref) => TabEncap());

class TabEncap extends StateNotifier<int> {
  TabEncap() : super(0);

  void set(int i) {
    print(state);
    state = i;
  }
}

class UserPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // Watch the tabProvider and get its value
    final currentIndex = ref.watch(tabProvider);

    print("render");

    final List<Widget> _children = [
      Text("zero"),
      Text("one"),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[currentIndex],
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).set(0);
              print(ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state);
            },
            child: Text("Zero"),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 16),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).set(1);
              print(ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state);
            },
            child: Text("One"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

QUESTION

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart'; 


final tabProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

class UserPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UserPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    // Watch the currentIndexProvider and get its value
    var currentIndex = ref.watch(tabProvider.notifier).state;

    print("render");
      
    final List<Widget> _children = [
      Text("zero"),
      Text("one")
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(index: currentIndex, children: _children,),
      bottomNavigationBar: GNav(
        tabs: const [
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.add,
            text: 'zero',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.person,
            text: 'one',
          ),
        ],

        selectedIndex: currentIndex,
        onTabChange: (index) => { 
          ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state = index, 
          print(ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state)
        }

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output

```
render
0
1
0
1
0
```

I don't understand why riverpod doesn't call a re-rendering of this component, it just stays on the initial tab even though the state changes

I tried different river pod state providers
StateProvider and NotifierProvider

```
final tabProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

//OR

final tabProvider = NotifierProvider<TabEncap, int>(TabEncap.new);
class TabEncap extends Notifier<int> {
  @override
  int build() { return 0; }

  void set(int i) {
    print(state);
    state = i;
  }
}
```

and using methods instead of state = ... like

```
ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).set(index)
```

i've tried not using a gnav bar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final tabProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

class UserPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // Watch the currentIndexProvider and get its value
    var currentIndex = ref.watch(tabProvider.notifier);

    print("render");

    final List<Widget> _children = [
      Text("zero"),
      Text("one"),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[currentIndex.state],
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state = 0;
            },
            child: Text("Zero"),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 16),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state = 1;
            },
            child: Text("One"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is also another example which isn't working

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:mutual2/providers.dart';
import 'package:mutual2/structs.dart';


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Define your data model (Liked) here


class LikedEncap extends Notifier<Liked> {
  @override
  Liked build() {
    return []; // Initialize with an empty list
  }

  void add() {
    state = [...state, "add"]; // Add an item to the list
    print(state);
  }
}

final likedProvider = NotifierProvider<LikedEncap, Liked>(LikedEncap.new);


class UserPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final liked = ref.watch(likedProvider.notifier).state;

    print("render");

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('User Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Display your data here (e.g., a ListView of liked items)
            // ...

            Text(liked.toString()),

            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Call the 'add' method to update the data
                ref.read(likedProvider.notifier).add();
              },
              child: Text('Add Item'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have also tried using a consumer

```
    
class UserPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


      
    final List<Widget> children = [
      const Text("zero"),
      const Text("one"),
    ];


    return Consumer(builder : (context, ref, child) {
      var currentIndex = ref.watch(tabProvider.notifier).get();
      return Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(index: currentIndex, children: children,),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
          child: GNav(
            gap: 10,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            color: Colors.white,
            activeColor: Colors.white,
            tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
            tabs: const [
              GButton(
                icon: Icons.add,
                text: 'zero',
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              GButton(
                icon: Icons.person,
                text: 'one',
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
            selectedIndex: currentIndex,
            // Use the provider to update the current index when a tab is tapped
            onTabChange: ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).set
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.notifier` when accessing `tabProvider` in build method.
Try this way :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';

final tabProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

class UserPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // Watch the currentIndexProvider and get its value
    var currentIndex = ref.watch(tabProvider);

    print("render");

    final List<Widget> _children = [
      Text("zero"),
      Text("one"),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: currentIndex.state,
        children: _children,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: GNav(
        tabs: const [
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.add,
            text: 'zero',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.person,
            text: 'one',
          ),
        ],
        selectedIndex: currentIndex,
        onTabChange: (index) {
          ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state = index
          print(ref.read(tabProvider).state);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `var currentIndex = ref.watch(tabProvider);` gives you the value.  You don't need to keep adding .state on that.

Comment: But when I need to access `.state` when setting the new value in the `onTabChange` callback.

Comment: ref.watch(tabProvider) to get the value.  ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state = to set the value.

Comment: Yeah I got that but I havenot used `.state` in `var currentIndex`.

Comment: `selectedIndex: currentIndex.state` that's wrong. It should be `selectedIndex: currentIndex`. And in onTabChange, it should be `ref.read(tabProvider.notifier).state = index`

Comment: This answer could be ok if you were NOT using `state`. Just use the value provided by   `watch` and change the state using the method `set()` from the notifier.

Comment: Hi This is the original poster, I've tried your solution but unfortunately i get this error : The getter 'state' isn't defined for the type 'int'.
Try importing the library that defines 'state', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'state'.dartundefined_getter

Comment: I think you might only be supposed to not use .notifier if you are using futures?

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentIndex = 0;
Consumer(
  builder: (context,ref,_) {
    currentIndex = ref.watch(tabProvider);
    return IndexedStack(
      index: currentIndex,
      children: _children,
    );
  });
}
```

The Expression  'ref.watch(tabProvider);' should be placed in a consumer

Comment: Hi, this hasn't worked sorry, see my updated question